# D3 - how to include č,š,ž letters in D3

Tags: utf-8, d3.js, character-encoding, letters

I'm beginner in D3. I would like to know how to include in text letters like č,š,ž..

I included line with utf-8:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I also tried this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="D3/d3.js"></script>
```

Letters like č,š or ž are shown like �. That is the same with letters from .text("Število...") and also with words from loaded file *.csv.

I tried change letter č with code

```
&#269;
```

but no success.
What can I do? Please help.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <title>Slo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D3/d3.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .naslov {
            fill: #505050;
            font: 18px sans-serif;}

        .podnaslov {
            fill: #777;
            font: 12px sans-serif;}

        .besedilo {
            fill: #777;
            font: 8px sans-serif;}

        .land {
            fill: #ccc;
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-linejoin: round;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            stroke-width: .5;}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var w = 1000;
var h = 450;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f");

var radius = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, 1e6])
    .range([1, 90]);    

//Projekcija
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(11000)
    .translate([-2480,10270]);

//Path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)

//Napisi
var naslov = svg.append("text")
    .text("PREBIVALSTVO V SLOVENIJI PO NASELJIH")
    .attr("class", "naslov")
    .attr("x",15).attr("y",30);
var podnaslov = svg.append("text")
    .text("LETA 2002 in 2013")
    .attr("class", "podnaslov")
    .attr("x",15).attr("y",60);
var besedilo1 = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "besedilo")
    .text("Velikost kroga kaže na stevilo prebivalcev v naselju leta 2013.").attr("x",15).attr("dy",100);
var besedilo2 = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "besedilo")
    .text("Prikazani so podatki za naselja, ki so imela leta 2013 vec kot 1300 prebivalcev.").attr("x",15).attr("dy",112);
var besedilo3 = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "besedilo")
    .text("Zadrži miško na krogih in si oglej podatke.").attr("x",15).attr("dy",124);

//Load in GeoJSON data
d3.json("Obstara.geojson", function (data){
        svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class","land")       
});

//Load mesta
d3.csv("Mesta_02_13.csv", function(error,podatki) {
    if (error) return console.error(erorr);

   svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(podatki)
       .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.trinajst-d.dva <= 0) {return "#9D5355"}
            else    { return "#006699"};})
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];})
        .attr("r", function(d) { return radius(d.trinajst); })
        .style("stroke","grey")
        .style("stroke-width", '0.3px')
        .style("opacity", 0.6)
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.trinajst-d.dva <= 0) {return "#9D5355"}
            else    { return "#006699" };});})
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n2002: " + d.dva + "\n2013: " + d.trinajst; })
});


    </script>
</body>
```

I loaded csv file where are also included names with č,š,ž letters:

> ```
> name,lat,lon,dva,trinajst
> Ljubljana,46.0605,14.5166,258873,274826
> Maribor,46.5620,15.6482,93847,94809
> Celje,46.2524,15.2765,37834,37490
> Mengeš,46.1686,14.5731,5557,6202
>  ...
> ```

Comment: How are you creating the file containing these characters? How are you saving it? In what encoding? Does manually changing the encoding in your browser to some other encoding make them show up correctly? If so, which one?

Comment: Show actual code that reproduces the issue and check whether your files are in fact UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I added code to up quastion.

Comment: Thank you! You made me thinking differently. I found out that I can set coding in Notepad++ , where I saved my files (csv, html) last. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

As may others have the same problem:

**First** you need to change the encoding of the document and save it once in `UTF-8` format, and **then** put your `UTF-8` texts inside that document.